# Why Swift Set fucntion Why firstIndex(of: ) Apply?

Tags: swift, set

I understand Set Collection is key-value and Keys are not duplicated.

In the example below, I thought fruits were the key.

however .firstIndex(of: ) is exist why?

So can a second index exist?

Am I misunderstanding the set?

```
var favoriteFruits: Set = ["Banana", "Apple", "Orange", "Orange"]

favoriteFruits.insert("WaterMelon")
print(favoriteFruits)
favoriteFruits.remove("Banana")
print(favoriteFruits)

if favoriteFruits.contains("Tomato") {
    print("Tomato is my favorite Fruits")
} else {
    print("Tomato is not my favorite Fruits")
}

print(favoriteFruits.firstIndex(of: "Orange"))
```

It would be of great help if you leave a comment.

Comment: *I understand Set Collection is key-value*. Kind of, but the ***key*** (aka the hash) is not exposed to the user. From the perspective of the user `Set` is index based like Array, but the items are unique and unordered.

Comment: I understand that you are confused. I math, a set is an unordered set of unique elements. It makes therefore no sense to speak of an index. However in computer science, sets are often implemented as arrays, and you have even ordered sets. While in the 1st case it still makes no sense to assign an index to an element, in the 2nd case it does.

Answer (score 1):

If you check [firstIndexOf method's explanition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/firstindex(of:)) you will see a defition :

```
Available when Element conforms to Equatable.
```

Sets conforms to `Equatable`.You can also test this while checking the equality of the two sets.Below code doesn't give any error.

```
if set1 == set2{
  //....
}
```

> You ask  .firstIndex(of: ) is exist why?

So there is no obstacle for the collection type of `Set` to use the `firstIndexOf` method

If you ask `why set is equatable`.Set uses the hash table to check the elements inside. So the `Set must be hashable`.An object that conforms to `Hashable` must also be `Equatable` too

Comment: thanks for the nice answer! Can we consider that firstIndex is implemented as mandatory for Set to conform to collection type?

Comment: firstIndex is not mandatory implemented. It only means that collection type can be used if it conforms to Equatable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a consequence of `Set<String>` conforming to `Collection<String>`. The `Collection` protocol requires [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/firstindex(of:)):

```
func firstIndex(of element: Self.Element) -> Self.Index?
```

The associated types `Element` and `Index` are also required by the `Collection` protocol. Even if `Set` is not index-*based*, `Set` does declare a nested struct called [`Index`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/index). See its implementation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Set.swift#L1278).

It is true that there can be no "second" index for a particular element, since elements in a set are unique. `firstIndex(of:)` and `lastIndex(of:)` for any element for a set would return the same thing.

However, the `Collection` protocol does not care. After all, functions that can take any `Collection` does not know what kind of collection they are working with, e.g.

```
func someGenericFunction<C: Collection>(collection: C) {
    // ...
}
```

so they need to specify whether they want the first, last, or the nth index of a particular element, so that their code works for all kinds of collections. If `Set` did not have these methods, then `Set` is not a `Collection`, and cannot be passed to these functions.

Comment: thanks for the nice answer! Can we consider that firstIndex is implemented as mandatory for Set to conform to collection type?

Comment: @CookKim yes. That is basically what I said.